# Auto login on Openfire server on successfully login in PHP

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I have integrated simple chat functionality using XMPP + Openfire in my web application. i want to do auto login on Openfire server after login in my application... how can i do??

I have openfire user name and password

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use http-prebind. [prebind-php](https://github.com/BenJaziaSadok/xmpp-prebind-php)

Once you get jid,sid,rid attach them to your xmpp client and get connected securely (without need to write your login/password in javascript)